# Running time of modified BFS algorithm to find shortest path in weighted DAG

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

While the shortest path can be calculated with $O(V+E)$ time over a weighted directed acyclic graph using topological sort, I wonder about the running time of the following BFS type algorithm I thought of.

```
BFS_requeue(v):
Initialization()
push(s) //push the source node
while the queue contains at least one vertex:
    u = pull()
    for all edges u -> v
        w = edge_weight(u,v)
        if dist(v) > dist(u) + w
            dist(v) = dist(u) + w
            pred(v) = u
            push(v)
```

> Compare one of the standard BFS algorithms, this does not mark vertices, and one vertex can be pushed into the queue more than once. Although it seems that popping a vertex more than once can result in a slower running time in general, I am not sure with the exact running time of the algorithm on a **(possibly negative) weighted directed acyclic graph.**

Although I suspect in the worst case, this runs like Bellman-ford, in $O(VE)$ time, I cannot think of a concrete example. All the examples I thought of run in $O(V+E)$ time. So what is the running time of this algorithm on a weighted DAG?

I think regardless of the running time, this does identify the shortest path, essentially by relaxing all edges. However, I might be incorrect.

---

This algorithm is taken from page 7 of [chapter 8 of Jeff Erickson's textbook on algorithms](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/08-sssp.pdf). I have only modified the algorithm so it applies to weighted graphs. Nonetheless, this problem is specifically about DAG, rather than weighted graphs in general

Comment: Can the queue contain a single vertex more than once, or if the vertex v is already in the queue, does push(v) do nothing?

Comment: No need to use "Edit:" - instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: @D.W. I copied this from Jeff Erickson's textbook, only modifying the weights from unweighted to weighted. I probably should've cited him. In this case, I'm not completely sure, but I think if the vertex v is already in the queue, it still pushes in. Does it matter anyway though? Thank you for sharing the link about editing, I'll be careful in the future.

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your post to provide a full citation to the original source of the problem.

Comment: @D.W. I have added the source for the algorithms. I guess the source of this problem is that it pops up in my brain while learning the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The running time can be exponential, so it is much worse than $O(|V|+|E|)$ or $O(|V| \cdot |E|)$.

Here is an explicit counterexample. Suppose you have a dag with $n$ vertices, numbered $1,2,\dots,n$, and there is an edge $i \to j$ for each $i,j$ with $i > j$, with weight $2^{i-j}-1$.  Suppose that the for-loop traverses the neighbors from lowest-numbered vertex to highest-number vertex.  The algorithm will start by visiting vertex $n$, then pushing $1,2,\dots,n-1$ onto the queue, visit vertex $1$, then $2,1$, and so forth.  In particular, the condition `dist(v) > dist(u) + w` will always hold true, so the then-branch of the if-statement will always be executed.

What's the running time, on this graph, with this visit order?  It satisfies the recurrence relation

$$T(n) = T(1) + T(2) + T(3) + \dots + T(n-1),$$

which solves to $T(n) = 2^n$.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, in this case, there are $\Theta(n^{2})$ edges, so $\Theta(n^2) = \Theta(V+E)$? I felt that that $Theta(V+E)$ also works.

Comment: @wsz_fantasy, you are right.  My analysis was wrong.  I have revised my answer, and I think it is now correct.  Please do check it for yourself and see whether it seems right to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you please also include the edge weights in this counterexample?

Comment: @wsz_fantasy, Ahh, good point!  I've included edge weights now.